# No value For Json Object Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am having an error with volley in my android app 
I am trying to display Json in a dropdown

The error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for UserRate
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
        at com.smartpractice.myapplication.EditProject$16.onResponse(EditProject.java:794)
        at com.smartpractice.myapplication.EditProject$16.onResponse(EditProject.java:776)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
```

The Json Data

```
{"success": 1,"Project": [{"UserName": "Ruben Meiring - UserID: 62"},{"TaskName": "Accommodation Cost - TaskCode: Acc001"},{"UserRate": "62 - 1 - R 0"},{"UserRate": "62 - 2 - R 0"},{"UserRate": "62 - 3 - R 0"},{"BudgetHours": "0"}]}
```

And The Volley Code

I know This code works Because when I change the URL and the object I am looking for to other data it displays fine

The thing is I know the Url works because I can Get the data via postman

```
    private  void  loadStaffSpinner(String url){
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(EditProject.this);

        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Project Data");

        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        pd.show();

        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicat

ionContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                pd.cancel();

                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {

                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Project");

                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String Phase=jsonObject1.getString("UserRate");

                            StaffArray.add(Phase);

                        }

                    }

                    StaffList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(EditProject.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, StaffArray));
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner123",-1);
                    if(spinnerValue != -1) {
                        // set the selected value of the spinner
                        ClientSpinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override

            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                pd.cancel();

                error.printStackTrace();

            }

        });

        int socketTimeout=30000;

        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

I don't Know why I am having these issues might it be JSON data related? or something

Comment: What are you trying to achieve you need to change JSON response and add UserRate in another array which consists all UserRate rather than having three key with same name.

Comment: I am Going  to display them in a dropdown, on the server side I am saying which one to display, I get the same error when I call "UserName" and "TaskName" thats also in the JSON above